# SQLite DB crash

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

Below is the code for fetching data in sqlite db:

```
-(id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"CourseFindr" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_db) != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    sqlite3_close(_db);
}

- (NSArray *)job {
    NSMutableArray *retrieve = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *query = @"SELECT jID, jName, jDesc, jEarnings, jTags FROM jobs";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int _jID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            char *jNameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1);
            char *jDescChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
            char *jEarningsChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text (statement, 3);
            char *jTagsChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
            NSString *_jName =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:jNameChars];
            NSString *_jDesc = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:jDescChars];
            NSString *_jEarnings = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:jEarningsChars];
            NSString *_jTags = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:jTagsChars];
            Jobs *jobs = [[Jobs alloc]
                          initWithJID:_jID
                                jName:_jName
                                jDesc:_jDesc
                            jEarnings:_jEarnings
                                jTags:_jTags];
            [retrieve addObject:jobs];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    return retrieve;
}
```

But it keeps getting this crash:

```
2014-01-09 21:12:39.565 CourseFindr[4595:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x018255e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015a88b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x018253bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Foundation                          0x0120fb49 -[NSString initWithUTF8String:] + 89
    4   CourseFindr                         0x000036b5 -[CourseFindrDB jobs] + 645
    5  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e61725 start + 0
    6  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I'm not sure if it's because of my libsqlite3.dylib or is it not compatible with my database?
My database is named 'CourseFindr.sqlite' table is

```
JOBS Table
-jID PK
-jName
-jDesc
-jEarnings
-jTags
```

Also it keeps redirecting to main.m when it crashes.

I've done this before, but there were no errors. This time I'm trying it without tutorials, but it seems I'm missing something. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash log:

> 2014-01-09 21:12:39.565 CourseFindr[4595:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

is telling you that you are passing a NULL pointer to `initWithUTF8String`. This is the reason of the crash and is expected behaviour according to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithUTF8String%3a):

> initWithUTF8String:
>
> …
>
> Important: Raises an exception if bytes is NULL.

So, inspect what you are passing into the `initWithUTF8String` method and add guards against passing NULL. Something like:

```
char *jNameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1);
...
NSString *_jName = jNameChars?[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:jNameChars]:@"";
```

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. But can I just set them to be not NULL in the sqlite manager?

Comment: @sergio The OP is accessing columns 0-4, not 1-4. Look again at the code in the question.

Comment: @user3172172: glad to have helped! about your question: how can you set them to be not NULL in sqlite, well it depends on the data in your table. furthermore, there is always the chance of an error, in which case you would also get NULL… in any case, you need to guard against this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution in the first line of the exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
```

Which means that you are passing a null string to the initWithUTF8String method.

Answer (score 0):

NSLog all strings you are passing. because you are passing a null to `initWithUTF8String`